# Are those two AC bridges equal. If not, how do they behave differently?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, bridge

I do not understand if the following circuits are equal or if there's any difference in how they behave.
[image]

[image]

I assumed that it depends on the current, but then I have seen both used with AC and DC, so now I am confused whether or not it's a mistake or the circuits are just equal.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: that is a schematic diagram ... i does not represent how the components are positioned physically

Answer (score 2):

The components are connected identically between nodes. There is no difference.